# Passing data to UIView from UIViewController is not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift

I am sending data from UIViewController to UIView and the problem that I am facing is when I set the data to label its not displaying it. Before I set that data I am printing the data and its being printed.

```
class SearchDetailsView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var hiraganaLbl: UILabel!

    var nameNew = String()

    required init(name: String){
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.nameNew = name
        self.commonInit()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }


    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SearchDetailsView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(self.contentView)
        print("name is \(self.nameNew)")
        self.hiraganaLbl.text = self.nameNew
    }


}
```

The print function is printing the data that i passed from the UIViewController but is not being set to the label.

Comment: Are you using .xib for SearchDetailsView or what? You're writing code for both.

Comment: Yes I am using .xib

Comment: Instead of passing it in init function (constructor), You can write a new public method and call it to set text to your label when you want to set that. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `xib` for `SearchDetailsView`, there is no need to use `init` to get a new instance of `SearchDetailsView`.

Simply use a `class` method `loadNib(with:)` to get a new `SearchDetailsView` instance.

```
class SearchDetailsView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var hiraganaLbl: UILabel!

    var nameNew: String? {
        didSet {
            self.hiraganaLbl.text = nameNew
        }
    }

    class func loadNib(with name: String?) -> SearchDetailsView? {
        if let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SearchDetailsView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? SearchDetailsView {
            view.nameNew = name
            return view
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

In the above code, `hiraganaLbl's` `text` is set in the `didSet` of `nameNew`.

In your `ViewController`, get the instance of `SearchDetailsView` using

```
if let detailsView = SearchDetailsView.loadNib(with: "Your Name") {
    //add your code here...
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error now Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<JapneseNepaliDictionary.SearchDetailsView 0x10d26f848> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key contentView.'

Comment: Check if the outlets of the CustomView are connected properly.

Comment: Remove contentView outet in SearchDetailsView  if not required.

Comment: Have you removed it from both xib and swift file?

Comment: What to remove ?? I already removed Content view outlet but again its causing same problem.

Comment: Yes I have removed both from the swift and xib file and i am using the same code in the answer.

Comment: Can you print the error after removing the contentView outlets?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing it in `init` function (constructor), You can write a new public method and call it to set text to your label when you want to set that. it should work. Like

```
var nameNew: String;

 .... other code

public func setTextToLabel(nameNew: String) 
{
     self.nameNew = nameNew;
     self.hiraganaLbl.text = self.nameNew   
}
```

And call this method from your `ViewController`, where you are showing this view.

Comment: I have already tried that, the data is being passed but the text in the label is not being set. If i put static text then it will be set.

Comment: Its the same above class that I have posted in the question with additional function like you have recommended but still didn't work. :(

Comment: may be you are creating a new object of 'SearchDetailsView' of class and calling the method, in this way it will not set. You need to call it with the view which is loaded in your ViewController. May be through outlet from your storyboard. like your_outlet_ searchDetailsView.setTextToLabel(nameNew: "name");

Comment: please share your ViewControler code, then I can solve that. problem is there.

Comment: `let searchView = SearchDetailsView()
 searchView.setName(name: "My name")`

Comment: yup, here you are doing wrong, don't create a new object, of SearchDetailsView(). Use outlet from your storyboard in your view controller and call the function for that object.

Comment: this let searchView = SearchDetailsView(). Is not the object rendered to your Viewcontroller, its a new object you are creating.

Comment: Ok, then let me know did you add this SearchDetailsView in storyboard in your viewController? or you are adding this view on runtime in swift?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by doing the following in ViewController class:

`@IBOutlet var searchDetailView: SearchDetailsView!`

and set text to label by referencing the following way:

`searchDetailView.hiraganaLbl.text = dictionaryDataList[indexPath.row].japaneseHiragana`

and removed sending the text from init() method.